# Firebase - fetching a user's account without specifying UID nor email address

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have made an Ionic-Angular app that generates fake data in bulk to my Firebase database. It can generate multiple kinds of data separately:

- new `user accounts` (using Firebase Authentication)
- new `user profile` documents (in a "profiles" collection in Cloud Firestore)
- other types of data that relate to individual users in other collections in Firestore.

So that I know which documents are associated with which user, I would like the user's `uid` property to be the name of all of his/her documents (a.k.a. the user's document in the "foo" collection would be located at `foo/${uid}`).

Hence, if I want to generate 10 documents for the "foo" collection, I need the `uid` of 10 users, whichever they are. Is it possible to fetch the latter? It would be an equivalent to `admin.auth().getUser(uid)`, but without a specified `uid` (hence giving me a random, unspecified user).

I could store `uid`s in a separate document when I generate the accounts to then fetch them when I need them, but I don't want to go through the hassle of doing so and the logic that comes with it.

Comment: There is a `listUsers()` method in the Admin SDK, which "retrieves a list of users" but the selection is not random: it is normally used to retrieve all the users of a specified project in batches. If you want to loop over the users and check if an id was already used or not, you could use it... but I don't think you will save much time compare to storing uids in a separate Firestore document when you generate the accounts.

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was looking for. The users don't need to be properly random, just unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do (listing users in Firebase Auth) from a client app isn't possible.  It would be a massive security hole to allow end users to discover lists of all other end users by default.

If you want to list users, you should write backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK.  It has a way to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).  If you need to invoke this from the client app, you will need to find a way to wire that up yourself, perhaps using Cloud Functions or some other backend.

Comment: I would be the only one using that fake-data-generating app! Its sole purpose is to fill my database with fake data to aid my work on the main app I am developing.

Comment: That doesn't really change anything - Firebase Auth was built for security, so you have to work within its parameters.